# How to update data in elasticsearch with using like bulkupdate in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, go, elasticsearch

I find solution to update data in elasticsearch with golang. The data is about 1,000,000+++ documents and must be specific with id of document. I can update in mongoDB with using bulk operation but I can't find it in elasticsearch it is have a operation like it? or anyony have idea to update huge of data in elasticsearch with  specific id. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/olivere/elastic/wiki/BulkIndex 
this is example for using bulk data in elas. For who want to use like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can use bulk API to make such bulk updates. You can either index data again using same id or just run update. You can use CURL to push the updates from command line, if you are doing it as one off update.

```
POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
{ "update" : {"_id" : "1", "_index" : "test"} }
{ "doc" : {"field2" : "value2"} }
```

Other option is to use update_by_query, if you are setting custom fields. With update by query, you can also mix it with pipeline to update existing data.

It entirely comes down whether you are trying to run update using information from different index (in such case, you can use enrich processor, which is available in 7.5 onwards) OR if you simply want to add a new field and update it using some rule which already uses attributes available on the document.

So for different type of scenario, different options are available. Bulk API is more appropriate, when the data source is external. But if data is already available on Elasticsearch, then update by query is appropriate.

You can also look at reindexing with pipeline scripting. But again, horses for courses rule applies here as well.